# How many bits are needed to represent an instruction in a computer?

Tags: assembly, architecture, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, machine-instruction

How many bits are needed to represent an instruction in a computer that has 53 different instructions, all of which are two addresses, when the computer has 65000-word memory ?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think, I am lacking some basics.

Comment: Then it might be a good idea to go through your script. If it is not completely shit, then there should be enough material to answer your questions.

Comment: Perhaps you can think this way: How many bits do you need to count to 53? You surely cannot use fewer bits and still get unique values. And how many bits to count to 65000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I got you right, "all of which are two addresses"

Let's assume the wanted instruction may look like this `<Instruction ><Operator1><Operator2>`

you say there's 53 instructions, so let's create a list, and check how many bits are used:

```
number   instruction
00000000 operation1
00000001 operation2
00000010 operation3
...
00110100 operation52
00110101 operation53
```

as you see, only 6 bits of the eight are used, which makes sense, `2**6 = 64`
to address 65000 words, you need 16 bit (`2**16=65536`)

to encode an instruction with 2 operants, 16 bit each, you'd need

6 (for the instruction) +16 (op1) +16 (op2) = 38 bit

Comment: Isn't it necessary to convert words into bytes.

Comment: not always. depends on how that CPU adresses the RAM. afaik, ARM is using word adressing inside its opcodes, too. BUT: then you can only use adresses that are aligned

Comment: the ARM branch instructions e.g. are encoded what way. they include the relative adress in 32-bit words, not in bytes